# What would big/difficult/formal words be like in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

Latin has approximately 40.000 words. A really small number for a language. How can we know when the word is "big" or formal in Latin? English uses the words from Latin to sound formal. I speak portuguese, and 80% of the words came from Latin.(This doesn't help. Believe me!)
I know that there are the ante-Classical, the Classical and the post, Classical words, the words from prose, and poetry.
Does Latin has such words?

Comment: Is that 40 000 the number of attested words in the extant literature or an estimate of the number of words spoken Latin is thought to have contained? Our picture of Latin is not as complete as that of many modern languages, so I'm not sure the comparison works.

Comment: Actually, the Oxford Latin dictionary says that Latin has approximately 40.000 entries for distinct words.

Comment: There are actually a ton of studies on this for other languages. It's a combination of rarity and complexity. I'll try to dig up some studies later, but this is not as straightforward as it would seem, nor is it limited to Latin.

Comment: For a Latin-specific answer I'd look into Asianism vs. Atticism and the use of Greek loans, but that requires reviewing more Cicero than I want to.